# SQL query with a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like

```
Id  WID  AID  DateValue
1    1    12  2015-07-10 15:14:46.770
2    1    13  2015-07-10 14:14:46.770
3    2    13  2015-07-10 13:14:46.770
4    2    13  2015-07-10 12:14:46.770
5    2    13  2015-07-10 11:14:46.770
```

Now, I want to get the `Id` value by grouping `WID`AND `AID`, then taking the `MAX` value from `DateValue`.

The desired output is

```
Output:
Id
1
2
3
```

I tried something like this

```
SELECT Id, MAX(DateValue) 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY WID, AID`
```

Though I don't want `DateValue` in the select but it is fine.

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want a query like this:

```
SELECT Id --or *
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WID, AID ORDER BY DateValue DESC) AS seqNum
    FROM yourTable) dt
WHERE (SeqNum =1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a correlated subquery like so:

```
SELECT Id FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE t1.WID = t2.WID AND t1.AID = t2.AID AND t1.DateValue < t2.DateValue
)
```